# collecting common terms in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Given a large expression, how can I collect the various powers of a variable within Mathematica?

For example:

```
p = (1 + a + x)^4;
Expand[p]
Out: 1 + 4 a + 6 a^2 + 4 a^3 + a^4 + 4 x + 12 a x + 12 a^2 x +
     4 a^3 x + 6 x^2 + 12 a x^2 + 6 a^2 x^2 + 4 x^3 + 4 a x^3 + x^4
```

Comment: do you have a short example of the types of expressions you are trying to collect? The current answers involve collecting terms in polynomial expressions, and they may not be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Collect[expression,variable]`. From the [help documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Collect.html?q=Collect&lang=en):

```
In[1]:=Collect[(1 + a + x)^4, x]
Out[1]=(1 + a)^4 + 4 (1 + a)^3 x + 6 (1 + a)^2 x^2 + 4 (1 + a) x^3 + x^4
```

Answer (score 4):

Or `CoefficientList`. Also from the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoefficientList.html?q=CoefficientList&lang=en):

```
In[1]:= CoefficientList[(1 + x)^10 , x]

Out[1]= {1, 10, 45, 120, 210, 252, 210, 120, 45, 10, 1}

In[1]:= CoefficientList[1 + a x^2 + b x y + c y^2, {x, y}]

Out[1]= {{1, 0, c}, {0, b, 0}, {a, 0, 0}}
```